# Find column index by searching column header of a Dataset in Apache Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Spark Dataset similar to the example below:

```
       0         1                  2          3
    +------+------------+--------------------+---+
    |ItemID|Manufacturer|       Category     |UPC|
    +------+------------+--------------------+---+
    |   804|         ael|Brush & Broom Han...|123|
    |   805|         ael|Wheel Brush Parts...|124|
    +------+------------+--------------------+---+
```

I need to find the position of a column by searching the column header.

For Example:

```
int position=getColumnPosition("Category");
```

This should return 2.

Is there any Spark function supported on `Dataset<Row>` datatype to find the column index or any java functions which can run on Spark dataset?

Comment: Even i am facing the same problem, some solution is much appreciated.

i tried with Java string_replace, which slows down the execution a little.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to access the schema and read the field index as follows:

```
int position = df.schema().fieldIndex("Category");
```

Comment: That was Helpful

Comment: Please don't post just unformatted code, a small sentence to explain is always welcome !

Comment: I am getting the following error when doing this: TypeError: 'StructType' object is not callable

Answer (score 4):

I have used index attribute for lists:

```
df.columns.index(column_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider this option (Scala implementation):

```
def getColumnPosition(dataframe: DataFrame, colName: String): Int = {
    dataframe.columns.indexOf(colName)
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that Spark UDF's take away optimization, thus you wouldn't want to define your own function if you can avoid it.

Comment: Yes, true @Sankar, but I'm not sure - how are UDFs related to this question?

Comment: @EliorMalul you are right, and it wasn't me who asked that :P